# VHDL - RC4 implementation

Tags: vhdl

I want to write an RC4 implementation in VHDL.

I have a problem with this part of code. Firstly I know my `if` is wrong. It should be like `while generating output do ...` or `while data_in > 0 do...` but I don't know how to write it...

```
when S2 =>
    IF(clk_count < a_width) THEN
        x_v := (x_s + 1) mod 2**a_width;
        y_v := (y_s + permutation(x_v)) mod 2**a_width;
        temp1 := permutation(x_v);
        temp2 := permutation(y_v);
        permutation(x_v) := temp2;
        permutation(y_v) := temp1;
        K := permutation(permutation(temp1) + permutation(temp2) mod 2**a_width);
        data_o <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(K, d_width));
        x_s <= x_v;
        y_s <= y_v;
        clk_count := clk_count + 1;
        current_state <= S2;
    END IF;
```

My program with `S2` is synthesizing for infinity (no end)...

All code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
--
ENTITY RC4 IS
    GENERIC
    (
        d_width : natural := 8;
      a_width : natural := 8
    );
  PORT
  (
        reset_i     : IN  std_logic; -- reset
        clk_i       : IN  std_logic; -- system clock
--      data_i      : IN  std_logic;
        data_in     : IN  std_logic_vector(d_width-1 DOWNTO 0); -- data input
        key_i       : IN  std_logic_vector(63 DOWNTO 0); -- key input
        data_o  : OUT std_logic_vector(d_width-1 DOWNTO 0)); -- data output
END ENTITY RC4;

--

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF RC4 IS
    SUBTYPE byte IS natural RANGE 0 TO 2**d_width-1;
    TYPE ram  IS ARRAY (natural RANGE <>) OF byte;
    SIGNAL key_table : ram(0 TO 7);
    type state_type is (S0, S1, S2);
    signal current_state: state_type;
    SIGNAL x_s,y_s : byte;

    BEGIN

        key_i_convert : PROCESS(key_i)
        BEGIN
            FOR i IN 7 DOWNTO 0 LOOP
                key_table(i) <= to_integer(unsigned(key_i((i+1)*8-1 DOWNTO i*8)));
            END LOOP;
        END PROCESS key_i_convert;
--
        crypt : PROCESS(current_state,clk_i,data_in,key_table)
            VARIABLE temp1,temp2,K : byte;
            VARIABLE permutation : ram(0 TO 2**a_width-1);
            VARIABLE j,x_v,y_v : byte;
            VARIABLE clk_count : INTEGER := 0;      
        BEGIN
--          IF(rising_edge(clock_i)) THEN
                    IF (reset_i = '0') THEN
                        data_o <= (OTHERS => '0');
                    END IF;
                    case current_state is
                        when S0 =>
                            IF(clk_count < 2**a_width) THEN
                                permutation(clk_count) := clk_count; 
                                clk_count := clk_count + 1;
                                current_state <= S0;
                            ELSE
                                clk_count := 0;
                                j := 0;
                                current_state <= S1;
                           END IF;
                        when S1 =>
                            IF(clk_count < 2**a_width) THEN
                                j := (key_table(clk_count mod 8) + permutation(clk_count) + j) mod 2**a_width;
                                temp1 := permutation(clk_count);
                                temp2 := permutation(j);
                                permutation(clk_count) := temp2;
                                permutation(j) := temp1;
                                clk_count := clk_count + 1;
                                current_state <= S1;
                            ELSE
                                clk_count := 0;
                                x_s <= 0;
                                y_s <= 0;
                                current_state <= S2;
                            END IF;             
                        when S2 =>
                            IF(clk_count < a_width) THEN
                                x_v := (x_s + 1) mod 2**a_width;
                                y_v := (y_s + permutation(x_v)) mod 2**a_width;
                                temp1 := permutation(x_v);
                                temp2 := permutation(y_v);
                                permutation(x_v) := temp2;
                                permutation(y_v) := temp1;
                                K := permutation(permutation(temp1) + permutation(temp2) mod 2**a_width);
                                data_o <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(K, d_width));
                                x_s <= x_v;
                                y_s <= y_v;
                                clk_count := clk_count + 1;
                                current_state <= S2;
                            END IF;
                    END CASE;
    --          END IF;
        END PROCESS crypt;
END ARCHITECTURE behavioral;
```

Comment: Did this design work correctly in simulation? How does the state machine ever get out of S2?

Comment: It's not work correctly becouse when I want to synthesize it's synthesizing for infinity time... I want to get out of S2 when I done generating output but i don't know how to do it. If u want I can paste here all my code... Pseudocodes that i'm using: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4_%28cipher%29) and [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ARC4)

Comment: The original disclosed [RC4 Source Code](http://web.archive.org/web/20080207125928/http://cypherpunks.venona.com/archive/1994/09/msg00304.html "RC4 Source Code") can be found in the Internet Archive.  When you say synthesizing for infinity time, do you mean it's not completing synthesis?  Which vendor and synthesis tool?

Comment: Like I asked, did it simulate correctly before synthesis? There is not much point synthesising it until it passes your tests.

Comment: Simulation is okay, Program: Xilinx

Comment: Now it's all code in my post.

Comment: Modulo 256 arithmetic can be accomplished by using std_ulogic based vectors (e.g. unsigned array type) defined as length 8.  For powers of two there's hardware equivalency. If declared as integer types are they range constrained? Show your declarations for everything in S2 and context clause at least.

Comment: Now it's everything in code...

Comment: While your rc4 entity analyzes and may well simulate it doesn't appear to implement the RC4 algorithm.  data_in only shows up two places, in it's port declaration and in the sensitivity list to the crypt process.  And as Brian asks, how do you get out of S2?

Comment: How to write sth like this: `data_o(clk_count) := data_in(clk_count) XOR K;`

Comment: @DavidKoontz i think it's what i want...

Comment: Without combining data_in and K (and data_in is a single byte) you have a pseudo random generator.  There's also no external indication what state  you're in.  I haven't attempted to validate anything.  There's an opencores rc4 implementation in verilog with a test bench, also [RC4 - someone help pleas!!](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.vhdl/gDKzfnZOr5M "RC4 - someone help pleas!!") stuck approximately where you are (and looks similar). The verilog README says keytable gen is very large.  Your design doesn't seem ready for synthesis.

Answer (score 1):

I've only had a quick look at your code but what I would suggest doing is moving your current_state assignment out of your IF statement because if the IF condition is never met for whatever reason, it will never update the current_state value.  Try that and let me kow if it makes a difference, if it doesn't I'll take a closer look at your code for you.

Gipsy